# Simple ongoing notification to allow audio to continue playing in the background

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I've decided to try to make a little Android application that streams live audio from my server. I'm using a HTML5 audio tag for the audio. But, on some devices when the user goes to the browser or their messages the music stops playing. Would I need to create an ongoing notification so the audio would continue to play? Or, would something else be better? I'm using PhoneGap too, I don't know if there's a plug-in out there that I've missed that could solve this. I'm trying to learn all of this on my own, but I'm just confused at this point.

Comment: ongoing notification is just a notification it won't solve your problem.

Comment: What then do you think would?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it ended up being a problem with the app manager just closing the app.